# KPI colour needs to appear based on conditions sharepoint 2010

Tags: dashboard-designer-2013

I need to develop a KPI, in which based on a column called Completed having Yes/No values in it. If Its Yes the item should display green color. If its No it should display red color. Your suggestions are welcome.Can somone provide me the steps.

Comment: Have a look at calculated columns.

Answer (score 0):

Display Templates or XSLT can created a nice dashboard from a list.  If you need a steer on XSLT then there are some guides on http://paylord.wordpress.com